# Tipo de dato para recibir archivo en Asp.net (C# ) enviado desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net, archivo

Tengo una página hecha en **HTML** y **JavaScript**, en esta tengo un formulario con varios `inputs` entre ellos se encuentra un `input file`, y se los envío al *servidor* por medio de **Ajax** y **JS**.

Del lado del servidor recibo los datos de los `inputs`, pero al recibir el `input file` me aparece un error de tipo de dato es incorrecto.

Mi pregunta es:
Que tipo de dato tengo que usar del lado del servidor (**ASP.net  y C#**) para poder recibir el archivo de manera correcta.

Aquí parte del código que tengo:

**HTML**

```
  <form id='frm1'>
     <input type='text' id='nombre'>
     <input type='file' id='balance'>
  </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
fuction guardar(){
 var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
 var files = $("#balance").get(0).files;
 PageMethods.Guardar(nombre,files[0],guardar_Callback, Failed_CallBack,context);
}
```

Del lado del *servidor* tengo el siguiente método:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static int guardar(string nombre, tipoArchivo balance){
//lo que haga con la informacion
}
```

Como les comente con excepción del tipo de dato para recibir el archivo, todo funciona bien.

Comment: Por el uso de PageMethods, parece que estas usando un ScriptManager. Si esto es correcto, lo mas seguro es que debes usar un UpdatePanel y controles de servidor. Revisa este link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16945/Simple-AJAX-File-Upload , de pronto te puede servir .

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez de echo si estoy usando el scriptManager, pero debido a ordenes de donde trabajo solo puedo usar controles **HTML**, si usara controles del lado del servidor seria mas fácil, pero no es asi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de mucho investigar y con los requerimientos mencionados de Usar **JavaScrip**, **PageMethods** y **WebMethod**, debo decir no es posible subir un archivo al servidor, debido a las limitantes de las propias tecnologías y su forma de trabajar.

Para poder realizar dicha acción es necesario o bien usar un `UpdatePanel` con controles del lado del servidor, que es lo que yo he terminado haciendo, como indicó [@weimar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42358/tipo-de-dato-para-recibir-archivo-en-asp-net-c-enviado-desde-javascript#comment72944_42358) y como muestra este enlace https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16945/Simple-AJAX-File-Upload

O usar MVC como muestra @Lazarok en su respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42734/24364

Answer (score 1):

> **Te adjunto un codigo usando ASP.NET MVC 4,esta es la estructura del proyecto**
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cuerpo del fichero Index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <input type="file" id="file" value="enviar" /><br />
    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ficheroSeleccionado(e) {
        if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
            subirFichero(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    }

    function subirFichero(file) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
            alert("Error subiendo el archivo.");
        }, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
            //Codigo subido OK
            alert("fichero subido: " + e.target.statusMessage + "->" + e.target.statusText);
        });
        xhr.open("POST", "@Url.Action("UpLoad")", true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    }

        document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", ficheroSeleccionado, false);

</script>

</html>
```

**Cuerpo del fichero UpLoad.cshtml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        OK
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Cuerpo del fichero IndexController.cs**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace SubiendoFicheroAJAX_ASP.MET.Controllers
    {
        public class IndexController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Index/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult UpLoad(string descripcion, HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
                if (file!=null)
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/" + file.FileName));
                return View();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: gracias pero no me ayuda mucho, ya que no estoy usando **MVC**, El cliente es `HTML` puro con `JavaScrip` El unico lugar donde hay código ASP.NET es en el `ScriptManager`